Why are "amd64.exe" installers not available for latest Python versions in https://www.python.org/ftp/python/?
I use pyenv and want to install Python 3.10.14 with it. But it is not available.
I first tried to update pyenv and checking the available Python versions.
pyenv update
pyenv install --list

But Python 3.10.14 was still not avaiable. After checking the mirror website https://www.python.org/ftp/python/ used by pyenv, I saw that Python 3.10.14 was present but the "amd64.exe" was not in there.
Edit:
I found out too late (after your answers, thanks for them) that python 3.10.11 is the last 3.10 version coming with an installer. I'll try to manually put the source code of 3.10.14 inside pyenv

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

See https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ – that version says "no files for this release".

From the release notes of Python 3.10.12 (as an example):

No installers
According to the release calendar specified in PEP 619, Python 3.10 is now in the "security fixes only" stage of its life cycle: 3.10 branch only accepts security fixes and releases of those are made irregularly in source-only form until October 2026. Python 3.10 isn't receiving regular bug fixes anymore, and binary installers are no longer provided for it. Python 3.10.11 was the last full bugfix release of Python 3.10 with binary installers.

